# DataProc HUB Instance with Internal IP address and no SSH access

Tags: deep-learning, google-cloud-dataproc, google-dl-platform

Would like to use GCP provided dataproc-container-v20210802-debian-10 image to create Dataproc HUB notebook instance. In organization the VM instances with External IP address and SSH connection to VM are not allowed.

We would like to use Dataproc HUB instance only into Internal network. My question is what additional changes would be required if I choose Internal IP address while creating Dataproc Hub instance and no SSH connection is available ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It should be okay to use internal-ip only cluster and there is no problem with SSH. See https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced#sshbetweeninstances

Comment: Hey @Dagang, can you add your comment as an answer to this post? This way everyone will have more visibility of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

It should be okay to use internal-ip only clusters and there is no problem with SSH:

```
gcloud compute ssh <name> --internal-ip ...
```

See [Connecting to instances that do not have external IP addresses](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced#sshbetweeninstances) for more details.